# Passing in a function as a function parameter

Tags: c#

I am trying to implement the trapezodial rule in c# as a function:

```
Int_a^b f(x) = (b-a) * [f(a) + f(b)] / 2
```

Is there a feature in c# which allows me to write the function as such?

```
double integrate(double b, double a, function f)
{
    return (b-a) * (f(a) + f(b)) / 2;
}
```

Where `f` can be any polynomial expression defined inside another function, for example:

```
double f (double x)
{
    return x*x + 2*x;
}
```

Comment: Yes. Read about `delegate`s

Comment: of course both of the answers are right *but* please note that this will not give you good results for most functions (you will have to split up `[a..b]` into small parts and use this rule to sum up those - or even more complicated formulas instead)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case you want to pass a `Func<double, double>`. Like so

```
double integrate(double b, double a, Func<double, double> f)
{
    return (b-a) * (f(a) + f(b)) / 2;
}

double integrand = integrate(0, 2 * Math.PI, x => x*x + 2*x);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do so using the `Func<>` generic type, where the first generic represents the passed type and the second represents the return type of the function:

```
double integrate(double b, double a, Func<double, double> f)
{
    return (b-a) * (f(a) + f(b)) / 2;
}
```

Your call would look like this:

```
var a = 1.0;
var b = 2.0;

var result = integrate(b, a, f);
```

Or if you prefer a lambda expression:

```
var result = integrate(b, a, x => x*x + 2*x);
```